# Is it possible to allow general public to mint NFT without being whitelisted?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, polygon, remix, nft

I am quite new to Solidity. I have deployed a smart contract and doing some testing on it. If no one was added as a whitelisted user - all wallets can mint an NFT. If I add someone and then remove them - no one can mint it until whitelisted (except the owner). My question: is it possible to allow everyone to mint again?  Thanks in advance.

contract:
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

```
contract test is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    string public baseURI;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    uint256 public cost = 0.03 ether;
    uint256 public presaleCost = 0.03 ether;
    uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
    uint256 public maxMintAmount = 10000;
    bool public paused = false;
    mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
    mapping(address => bool) public presaleWallets;

    constructor(
        string memory _name,
        string memory _symbol,
        string memory _initBaseURI
    ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
        setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
        mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }

    // internal
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        return baseURI;
    }

    // public
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
        uint256 supply = totalSupply();
        require(!paused);
        require(_mintAmount > 0);
        require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
        require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

        if (msg.sender != owner()) {
            if (whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
                if (presaleWallets[msg.sender] != true) {
                    //general public
                    require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
                } else {
                    //presale
                    require(msg.value >= presaleCost * _mintAmount);
                }
            }
        }

        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
            _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
        }
    }

    function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
        public
        view
        returns (uint256[] memory)
    {
        uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
        uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
        for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
            tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
        }
        return tokenIds;
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        override
        returns (string memory)
    {
        require(
            _exists(tokenId),
            "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
        );

        string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
        return
            bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
                ? string(
                    abi.encodePacked(
                        currentBaseURI,
                        tokenId.toString(),
                        baseExtension
                    )
                )
                : "";
    }

    //only owner
    function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        cost = _newCost;
    }

    function setPresaleCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner {
        presaleCost = _newCost;
    }

    function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner {
        maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
    }

    function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
        baseURI = _newBaseURI;
    }

    function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension)
        public
        onlyOwner
    {
        baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
    }

    function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
        paused = _state;
    }

    function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = true;
    }

    function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        whitelisted[_user] = false;
    }

    function addPresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = true;
    }

    function add100PresaleUsers(address[100] memory _users) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            presaleWallets[_users[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removePresaleUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
        presaleWallets[_user] = false;
    }

    function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{
            value: address(this).balance
        }("");
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mint function you have added condition for if address is not owner then this user needs to be whitelisted. If you want to mint nft by any address then remove this condition.

```
if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if (whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
            if (presaleWallets[msg.sender] != true) {
                //general public
                require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
            } else {
                //presale
                require(msg.value >= presaleCost * _mintAmount);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but why did it allow to mint from all wallets prior adding the whitelisted wallets?

Comment: Basically it is getting some cost for if user is not whitelisted